# Error to connect to FileZilla server using JSch SFTP client

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to connect on SFTP using localhost configurations but I get the following error. But when I use the same configurations on FilleZilla it works perfect...

At FilleZilla server:

```
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
(000017)06/08/2019 09:26:20 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000017)06/08/2019 09:27:21 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 421 Login time exceeded. Closing control connection.
(000017)06/08/2019 09:27:21 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

Here is the error in Java:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:269)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at br.com.wasys.nps.service.SftpService.test(SftpService.java:26)
```

Here is my Java code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

Session session = jsch.getSession("test", "localhost", 21);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword("root");
session.connect();

ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = channel;
```

Answer (score 2):

FileZilla is FTP server, not SFTP server.

JSch is SFTP client.

You cannot use JSch to connect to FileZilla server.

You have to use an FTP library, like [Apache Commont Net `FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).