# Is it possible to access an FTP server with JSch?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch, apache-commons-net

Currently, we are using `JSch` client to access the SFTP server. We are now moving from SFTP server to FTP server (supporting legacy systems).

Is it possible to access `FTP` server with `JSch` instead of `Apache commons-net FTP library`.

I've tried everything and it looks like it's not possible. Is there a workaround?

I'm trying to avoid refactoring the code to use `Apache commons-net FTP library`.

Comment: A workaround? JSch is an SSH implementation. Why would it be compatible with a random other protocol?

Comment: I know it's not going to be compatible. I just thought maybe someone else has come across this problem and might have found a workaround.

Comment: Again, what *"workaroud"*? The protocols are completely incompatible. See [Error to connect to FileZilla server using JSch SFTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57376061/850848).